# get empty string at server when trying to send json encoded string to url

Tags: c#, .net, json, vb.net, curl

Get empty string object when sending JSON encoded string in URL

```
            string jdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mylist);
            string jsonstr = "records=" + jdata;
            //File.WriteAllText("str.json", jsonstr);

            string url = "http://meraclass.com/staging/cron_attendance/synchronize";
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = 10000;
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(jdata);

            }
```

Here `mylist` is a list which stores data from a database and `mylist` will look like this:

```
mylist[name]=saurabh;
mylist[age]=26;
```

And so on..

Comment: please add your mylist class and data

Comment: can you clarify your issue? Your question isn't clear what you need help with.

Comment: `get empty string object when trying to send json encoded string to url` Where exactly do you "get" an empty string? At the server? At the first line? Do you get an exception? etc. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: at server i am getting empty string

Comment: What does the server side code look like?